# How am I able to change a value inside a private read only array outside a class?

Tags: c#, .net

Please see the code below:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MonthClass();
        string[] months = (string[])c.GetMonths();
        months[0] = "Thursday";

        var d = c.GetMonths();
        Console.WriteLine(d.First());
    }
}

public class MonthClass
{
    private readonly string[] _months =
    {
        "January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July",
        "August","September", "October", "November","December"
    };

    public IEnumerable<string> GetMonths() => _months;
}
```

Notice that `MonthClass._months` is private and read only.  However, the second call to `GetMonths` returns `Thursday` as the first element of the array instead of `January`.

How am I able to change the value of a private read only member outside of `MonthClass` and how can I prevent this?

After reading the answers and doing my own research. I believe the following will resolve the issue:

```
private readonly string[] _months =
{
    "January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July",
    "August","September", "October", "November","December"
};


public IEnumerable<string> GetMonths
{
    get { foreach (var month in _months) yield return month; }
}
```

Comment: To prevent this, use Array.AsReadOnly method when you return your private array from public methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetMonths()` returns a reference to an array. Anybody who has its return value, has a reference to the array, and they can change it.

So what if you happen also to have kept a private reference to the array that you returned from that public method? The public method returned a reference to the object. `readonly` applies to the reference, not to the object itself.

This code is functionally identical:

```
public class C {
    private readonly string[] _array = new [] { "foo" };
    public string[] GetArray() => _array;
}

public class D {
    public static void Test() {
        C c = new C();
        c.GetArray()[0] = "bar";
    }
}
```

**Here's how to fix it:**

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<String> GetMonths() {
    return Array.AsReadOnly(_months);
}
```

That will return a different actual object, one that actually forbids writing --
 not just a differently typed reference to the same array.

You may as well return ReadOnlyCollection instead of IEnumerable, since the actual object you're returning is indexable.

If you want to return an object that's mutable, but doesn't allow anyone to change the private `_months` field, this works:

```
public List<string> GetMonths() => _months.ToList();
```

And so does this:

```
var mutableMonths = c.GetMonths().ToList();
```

I implore you not to name a property "Get", and not to return a new object from a property. This is an appropriate case for a method.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to have a read only HashSet rather than a read only collection? +1.

Comment: ["Immutable" is how the hip kids say "readonly" these days](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467171(v=vs.111).aspx). If you don't want to mess with nuget, you could also return a `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, int>` with the array items for keys and `0` for values.

Comment: @w0051977 That'll fix it, absolutely. Your code now returns a new enumeration that isn't a reference to the array. For style points you could rewrite it as suggested in my last update, or as `GetMonths() => _months.Select(s => s);` -- like your version, that'll return a new enumeration. Thomas has some good ideas as well. There are a lot of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Thanks.  Which option do you prefer? Your option or my option? I think I prefer your option arguing that it is more modern.

Comment: I think I like `return _months.Select(s => s);` best, thinking it over, but it's really a matter of taste. I'd be sure to add a comment noting that it needs to be that way, so nobody "fixes" it by taking out the identity select.

Comment: Can I ask why you have named the parameter s' inside the lambda?

Comment: Could have called it `george`, but used s because it’s a string.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @EdPlunkett is correct. Nevertheless I want to point out and add a few things.

The line

```
string[] months = (string[])c.GetMonths();
```

is somewhat problematic since `GetMonths` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and the cast to `string[]` would fail if the implementation of `GetMonths` changes and returns something other than an array. You can change the line to

```
string[] months = c.GetMonths().ToArray();
```

Note that you *can* still change the elements in `months` but this won't change the values in your class.

If you want to stick with `IEnumerable<string>` an alterative implementation could be

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMonths()
{
    foreach (var month in _months)
        yield return month;
}
```

An other alternative could be using an indexer instead of the `GetMonths` method:

```
public string this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return _months[index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MonthClass
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _months = new List<string>(12)
    {
        "January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July",
        "August","September", "October", "November","December"
    }.AsReadOnly();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetMonths() => _months;
}
```

or just

```
public class MonthClass
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Months { get; } = new List<string>(12)
    {
        "January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July",
        "August","September", "October", "November","December"
    }.AsReadOnly();
}
```